# Jquery - Submit all forms by one button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Html:

```
<form class="allforms" method="POST" action="/auth/myaccount/personal">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH">
...
</form>

<button id="allsubmit" class="btn btn-info">Continue</button>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#allsubmit").click(function(){
        $('.allforms').submit();
    }); 
});
```

I have 3 forms in my html code like above.
My button is out of any my forms.
How to have one submit button for all my forms. I tried the click function but it doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Form submission is a synchronous action, so when you submit a form and then immediately submit a different form in your page, the first form's submission is canceled.

What you can do instead is make sure the forms are submitted asynchronous (using ajax):

```js
$(function() {
    $("#allsubmit").click(function(){
        $('.allforms').each(function(){
            valuesToSend = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax($(this).attr('action'),
                {
                method: $(this).attr('method'),
                data: valuesToSend
                }
            )
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="allforms" method="POST" action="">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH1">
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

<br />
<form class="allforms" method="POST" action="">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH2">
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

<br />
<form class="allforms" method="POST" action="">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH3">
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

<br />
<button id="allsubmit" class="btn btn-info">Continue</button>
```

> A few notes
>
> 1. This **will not** work with forms that have file-uploading (enctype="multipart/form-data")
> 2. You need to decide what to do after the submission is done (because nothing in the page will change).
> 3. You can't submit forms in stackoverflow-snippets, so don't try to run this here :)

Comment: Wrapping code snippet and saying `don't try to run this here` lol

Comment: @TânNguyễn only to make it readable (and support copy-to-answer, etc...) :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it but try this one:

```
$("#allsubmit").on("click", function(){
    $('.allforms').each(function(){
        $(this).submit();
    });
});
```

Note that all of your forms have to have `class="allforms"` attribute

Comment: It doesn't work. Is doing something like refresh but my values doesn't change. My jquery is 1.9.1 version.

Comment: When you submit the form i'll redirect you to the `action`, when you submit  all the forms what you expect?

Comment: First of all in this way it doesn't direct me to anywhere. Secondly when I tried to use individually buttons it works. So something else wrong is happening.
By submit I am expecting to change-update values from my database.

Comment: This isn't possible. it won't work. you can't submit multiple forms at the same time unless you combine them to one form or request.

Comment: Ok that was helpfull. I will try what you said. It seems possible.