# Submitting multiple HTML forms with one button (JQuery/Ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've seen many of the other questions that involve this concept, however many of them suggest just using JQuery, which I tried multiple ways with no success.. I've never used Ajax, and this seems to be the best way to go about this, can anyone help me out with how to implement this? (Ajax or JQuery or however..) Below is the code of the two forms I'm using; following it will be general Javascript idea I was trying to implement, however, I did try many variations of it. I tried using timeouts, and functions such as preventDefault(); and stopPropagation(); all with no luck..

```
<div container="row-fluid">
  <!-- This button appears if there are any items in stock within this warehouse -->
    <div class="span2" style="<?php if($row_pending['Wh'.$row_pending['DefaultWh'].'Net'] > 0){}else{echo "display:none;";}?>">
      <form method="post" name="ATCForm" id="ATCForm1">
        <input id="qtywh1" type="hidden" name="qty" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="wh" value="<?php echo $row_pending['DefaultWh'];?>">
        <input type="hidden"  name="ot" value="ship">
        <input type="hidden" name="net" value="<?php echo $row_pending['Wh'.$row_pending['DefaultWh'].'Net']; ?>">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-ac" name="ATC" id="ATC1" type="submit" onclick="submitBoth()" value="ATC">Add to Cart</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  <!-- This button appears if there are ZERO items in stock within this warehouse -->
    <div class="span2" style="<?php if($row_pending['Wh'.$row_pending['DefaultWh'].'Net'] <= 0){}else{echo "display:none;";}?>">
      <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="ATCForm" id="ATCForm1b">
        <input id="qtywh1b" type="hidden" name="qty" value="0">
        <input type="hidden" name="wh" value="<?php echo $row_pending['DefaultWh'];?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="ot" value="backorder">
        <input type="hidden" name="net" value="<?php echo $row_pending['Wh'.$row_pending['DefaultWh'].'Net']; ?>">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-bo" name="ATC" id="ATC1b" type="submit" value="ATC">Add to Backorder</button>
      </form>
    </div>
</div><!-- row-fluid -->
```

Basic Javascript Logic:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function{
  function submitBoth(){
    document.getElementById('ATCForm1').submut();
    document.getElementById('ATCForm1b').submit();
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: What you are trying to do is not possible. You are trying to submit two forms that do not open up a new page/tab. Either you need to target a new page or you need to use Ajax.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is something like: `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); xhr.open('POST', 'myForm.php', true); (etc.)`  There is much more to it than just that, but XMLHttpRequest() let's you make the upload synchronous (or even asynchronous) web requests.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery - Submit all forms by one button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40873893/jquery-submit-all-forms-by-one-button)