# Submit with one button multiple forms generated by loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

Sorry for spaghetti code :( I can't figure out why is it not working. Button submits only last form, but i want to submit every generated form. What can i do? I tried AJAX but it gives the same result. I wanted to recursively add selections but i think it's the hardest way and there is another solution.

```
 <table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Product Name</th>
     <th>Product Weight</th>
     <th>Product Image</th>
     <th>Status</th>
     <th>Choose suplier</th>
     <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   <?php        
   foreach ($result as $k=>$v)
   {
      $oid[] = $v['op_id'];
      $pui[] = $v['pui'];
      ?>
      <tr>
       <td><?php echo substr($v['name'], 0,10); ?></td>
       <td><?php echo substr($v['gram'], 0,10); ?></td>
       <td><img style="width: 50%" src="<?php echo $site_url.'images/'.$v['image']; ?>" alt=""></td>
       <td><?php echo substr($v['opia'], 0,10); ?></td>
       <td>
          <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="demo-form2" data-parsley-validate oidd="<?php echo $v['pui']; ?>" class="form-horizontal form-label-left sels<?php echo $v['op_id'];?>">
           <div class="form-group">
             <label class="">
             </label>
           <div class="" style="width: 100%">
           <?php
            $sups = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM product p, suplier s, prod_suplier ps WHERE p.u_id=ps.p_id AND ps.suplier_id=s.id AND p.u_id=:u_id GROUP BY s.id');
            $sups->execute(array('u_id'=>$v['pui']));
            $count_sups = $sups->rowCount();
            if ($count_sups==1) {
              $get_sups = $sups->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
              echo $get_sups['full_name'];
            } else {
            ?>
              <select style="" name="supliers" id="">
               <?php
                while ($get_sup=$sups->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                ?>
                 <option value="<?php echo $v['sfn']; ?>"><?php echo $get_sup['full_name']; ?></option>
          <?php }?>
              </select>
      <?php } ?>
           </div>
         </div>
       </form>
      </td>
      <td>
       <form style=" float: right;" method="POST" action="<?php echo $site_url.$state.'delete/' ?>">
       <input type="hidden" name="delid" value="<?php echo $v['oid'] ?>">
       <button type="button" onclick="dsomo(this);" name="dbtn" style="color: red; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); border:none;" href="">
       <i class="fa fa-trash fa-2x" ></i>
       </button>
       </form>
      </td>
     </tr>
<?php }?>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<button type="submit" id="acception" name="submit">submit</button>
<script async>
$('#acception').on('click', function () {
<?php
for ($i=0;$i<count($oid);$i++) {
?>
  $("tr>td>.sels<?php echo $oid[$i];?>").submit();
<?php } ?>
})
</script>
```

Comment: A submit triggers a reload of the page - therefore the other forms are not submitted. You can catch that by not reloading the page and instead send the form information to your backend via ajax.

Comment: @paskl I've tried ajax request, it gave the same result

Comment: What was the error with ajax?

Comment: @paskl it gives the last form as result

Comment: Did you try to give the forms a class? this can be a good example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40873893/jquery-submit-all-forms-by-one-button

Comment: We can not possibly tell you what you might have done wrong with that, if you don’t show us what you did first of all … so please edit your question to include what you attempted to do via AJAX. // If you need to send _all_ this data, then why is it divided over _multiple_ forms to begin with?

Comment: @MojoAllmighty I've given them unique classes. The form I'm talking about is the one cointaining select tags

Comment: @04FS as you can see there is a loop. I'm fetching data from mysql and this data in `$result` . How can it be not divided if I'm fetching a data?

Comment: Well by having `<form>` and `</form>` _outside_ of the loop …? _You_ are in charge of the output you are creating here.

Comment: @MojoAllmighty Thank you very much for link :) It helped me. I tried AJAX but i did it with unique classes, now it's working

Comment: Good job. Consider posting your solution so others can learn from it if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to MojoAllmighty I found the solution. As described in the link below if I want to submit multiple forms by one button I have to assign equal classes to form and use ajax for async submitting forms. So maybe it can be marked as a duplicate of a link below.

- [Jquery - Submit all forms by one button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40873893/jquery-submit-all-forms-by-one-button)